# Can I create a document styled java classes from RPC style WSDL?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am trying to generate client from a hosted wsdl. wsdl is in rpc style format but i want classes that are generated to be in document style format. How to do the same ?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the `WSDL` and modify it to `document` style before using it to generate code. But that may not be helpful as the server hosting the service might still expect RPC style request.